# How to mechanically derive the recursor of a type from its constructors?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, dependent-type

In Martin-Löf Dependent Type Theory a type is commonly prescribed by how to construct its canonical terms and how to show that its canonical terms are definitionally equal. This means that the definition of a type contains no explicit information at all about its recursor / induction principle and how it should behave.

Am I right to suppose that, given the constructors of a type, 
we already have an implicit characterization of its recursor / induction principle – in the sense that *there exists an algorithm that mechanically derives* the recursor / induction principle of this type?

If this is correct I would like to know:

1. How such an algorithm look like? (References are fine)
2. How is this all related to [Gentzen’s inversion principles](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theoretic-semantics/#InvPriHar)?

Comment: Cf. Peter Dybjer's [Inductive Families](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01211308?LI=true)

Answer (score 3):

[Section 5.6 of the HoTT book](https://books.google.si/books?id=LkDUKMv3yp0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA164#v=onepage&q&f=false) discusses the general schema for inductive types, including how to get the corresponding induction principle.

In short, yes there is a general way to derive the elimination principle from the signature (the description of the construcotrs), and it is of course algorithmic. Coq does it, for instance, when you define an `Inductive foo` and it generates the eliminator `foo_rect`.

Comment: Or doing pattern matching of inductive types in Agda.